# Databricks Log4J Custom Appender Not Working as expected

Tags: log4j, databricks, rollingfileappender, fileappender

I'm trying to figure out how a custom appender should be configured in a Databricks environment but I cannot figure it out.
When cluster is running, in `driver logs`, time is displayed as 'unknown' for my custom log file and when cluster is stopped, custom log file is not displayed at all in the log files list

```
#appender configuration
log4j.appender.bplm=com.databricks.logging.RedactionRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.bplm.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.bplm.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n
log4j.appender.bplm.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy
log4j.appender.bplm.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/log4j-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-bplm.log.gz
log4j.appender.bplm.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=logs/log4j-bplm.log
log4j.logger.com.myPackage=INFO,bplm
```

Above configuration was added to following files

- "/databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/executor/log4j.properties"
- "/databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/driver/log4j.properties"
- "/databricks/spark/dbconf/log4j/master-worker/log4j.properties"

After above configuration was added to above mentioned files, there are two issues which i cannot figure out.

1 - When cluster is running, if I go to `driver logs` in the list of log files, I can see my custom logfile generated, correctly populated, but time column is displayed as 'unknown'.
2 - When cluster is stopped, if I go to `driver logs` in the list of log files, my custom appender are not displayed. ( stdout, stderr, and log4j-active are displayed )

I also used different FileNamePatterns, but issues mentioned above seems to happens for any configuration I tried

```
log4j.appender.bplm.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/log4j-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.bplm.log.gz  - appender1
log4j.appender.bplm.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/log4j.bplm-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz  - appender2
log4j.appender.bplm.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/bplm-log4j-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz  - appender3
log4j.appender.bplm.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/bplm.log4j-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz  - appender4
log4j.appender.bplm.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/log4j-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.bplm.gz  - appender5
log4j.appender.bplm7.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/log4j-bplm-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz - appender7
log4j.appender.bplm8.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=logs/log4j-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}-bplm.log.gz - appender8
```

I also tried to put *-active in ActiveFileName, but result was the same

```
log4j.appender.custom.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=/tmp/custom/logs/log4j-bplm-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH}.log.gz 
log4j.appender.custom.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=/tmp/custom/logs/log4j-bplm-active.log
```